# How to make a smarty condition work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I having the following code in my JavaScript:

```
<script>
    {literal}
        // Wait for document to be ready before doing JS / Jquery magic
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Check if the status is allowed to become changed | If so disable status select and force ticket closure
        if(
            {/literal}'{$ticket.lock_date}'{literal} != null
            &&
            {/literal}'{$currentDate}'{literal} > {/literal}'{$ticket.lock_date}'{literal}
        ) {
            $('#status').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.select2project').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.select2lead').attr("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id='+'{/literal}{$ticket.id}{literal}'
            });
        }

        //more code down here
   {/literal}
</script>
```

The field in my DB at lock date is NULL. When I visit the document, the code above actives, even tho I specifically run at the first check "!= null".

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? It is really bogging me down in development.

Comment: So you're dynamically generating JS, right? Have you checked the JS this code produces? Can you post it here?

Comment: *"How to make a smarty condition work in javascript?"* -- Smarty processes the document on the server, it doesn't interact with JavaScript (but it can be used to build the JS script). JavaScript runs in the browser, long time after Smarty completed its job.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. You can close the `{literal}` block before the `if` line, write the `if` condition using Smarty variables then start another `{literal}` block. If you are using Smarty 3 (why would you use an older version?) then you don't need to use the `{literal}` block at all. All you have to do is to make sure the curly braces (`{` and `}`) are surrounded by spaces. This way Smarty treats them as literal and not as Smarty constructs.

Comment: @axiac What I want to achieve is for the php if check to be run when you go to the page. It should check the DB lock_date field for being NULL or not, and if it is not NULL + the current date is past the lock date, then the code inside the brackets should run.

Right now the code is always ran, even tho the DB field is NULL.

Comment: PHP is not involved in this question.

Comment: It is not? I am calling explicitly variables from my .php file that assign variables that are send to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is server side template engine - It works before output is send to the browser. When You adding its syntax keywords by JS - it's too late. This will never be readed and interpretet by smarty engine. Try to put Yours code to template and pass some flags to it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It came down to the point that JS reads my DB NULL value as an empty string.

```
<script>
  {literal}
    // Wait for document to be ready before doing JS / Jquery magic
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Check if the status is allowed to become changed | If so disable status select and force ticket closure
        var lock_date = '{/literal}{$ticket.lock_date}{literal}';
        var currDate = '{/literal}{$currentDate}{literal}';
        var ticketID = '{/literal}{$ticket.id}{literal}';

        if(lock_date !== null && lock_date !== '' && currDate > lock_date) {
            $('#status').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.select2project').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.select2lead').attr("disabled", true);
            $('.editBtnLink').hide();
            $('.editBtnSave').hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ticketAutoclose.php?id='+ticketID
            });
        }

    // Some more code

  {/literal}
</script>
```